# How to show timestamps for each line in Argo Workflows pods?

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I'm trying to figure out how to show a timestamp for each line of STDOUT of an Argo Workflows pod. The `init` and `wait` containers by default show a timestamp, but never the `main` container.

The Argo CLI has a `--timestamp` flag when [viewing logs](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_logs/).

Also the [argo-java-client](https://github.com/argoproj-labs/argo-client-java/blob/master/docs/WorkflowServiceApi.md#workflowServiceWorkflowLogs) has a `logOptionsTimestamps` property that also enables timestamps.

However I cannot find a similar option when defining a Workflow in YAML. I've gone through the [field reference guide](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/fields/) but haven't been able to find something to enable timestamps in the `main` container.

Does anyone know if this is possible, or how to enable them?

Thanks,
Weldon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `init` and `wait` log statements have timestamps is that the Argo executable's logger writes timestamps by default.

The `--timestamps` option does not cause the containers themselves to log timestamps. It just decorates each log line with a timestamp (`kubectl` has a similar option).

As far as I know, there's no way to declaratively cause code running in the `main` container to log timestamps. You'd have to modify the code itself to use a logger which inserts timestamps.